# Loop of form "for i in {1..171}" not working (only loops once, with i='{1..171}')

Tags: bash, ubuntu, wget

I am trying to wget files from a range of URLs. Following is my bash script

```
for i in {1..171}
do
    wget --mirror --random-wait -R gif,jpg,pdf  "http://www.example.com/member/members-directory/?mode=paging&Keyword=&Type=&pg="$i
done
```

It is just downloading one page.

But I am getting to see on my terminal that

```
Last-modified header missing -- time-stamps turned off.
2013-11-16 11:56:06 (34.2 KB/s) - `www.example.com/member/members-directory/index.html?mode=paging&Keyword=&Type=&pg={1..171}' saved [31073]
```

But as output all I got is one page.

Comment: What do you mean by downloading one page?  Doesn't the loop execute 171 times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me guess, it's downloading only the page `http://www.example.com/member/members-directory/?mode=paging&Keyword=&Type=&pg={1..171}` ? That is, not expanding `{1..171}` correctly.

Keep in mind that the `{N..M}` style sequence generation only works in bash, typically not in sh. So if the shebang of your script is `#!/bin/sh` try changing it to `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: +1.  As per the updated question, your _guess_ is correct.  Brace expansion doesn't happen in `sh`.

Comment: doesn't this presuppose the presence of a page name `{1..171}`

Comment: I added `!#bin/bash` at the start of the script. Is it the right way to change it?

Comment: @1_CR . Actually it did not. All it did was downloaded the `pg=1` for the URL `pg={1..171}` and I am just wondering how.

Comment: `pg={1..171}` is obviously invalid input for the website. It looks like it handled it as if it was `pg=1`. It's all pretty normal.